# Charts4J Solution to draw a graph with a lot of data (>2000)

Tags: java, jsp, charts4j

I need to draw a chart in a JSP. I am using Charts4J to create a chart in my controller and then I display it in my JSP. For the really simple charts, it works well. But I need to create a chart with a lot of data, more than 2000. From the Charts4J website:

If you have lots of data, roughly speaking, more than 2000 data points, your application should try to sample data less frequently, and use the simple encoding scheme. Otherwise, this technology may not be right for you. Alternatively, you can also try submitting a HTTP POST request.

So I tried to find any example of POST request but I can't find any. I am completely stuck on this problem. Is anyone know how to do this? Or is there a tutorial I have not found? Thanks for your help. By the way I am using Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed charts4j. Unfortunately, when I did the last release, I forgot to update the Javadoc so you cannot find the documentation you are looking for on the project page. If you [clone from github](https://github.com/julienchastang/charts4j) and build, you will be able to see the updated javadoc. Or see [here](http://goo.gl/aKnll).

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your answer. I have not tested it yet. I tried another API (flot) and it works well for now. I may switch back to charts4J if I encounter problems with this one too.